# SQL query to join results from two tables but also include rows that do not have counterparts in the other table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Given two tables APPLE and ORANGE,

```
NAME      APPLES
Alice     5
Bob       10
Trudy     1

NAME      ORANGES
Bob       50
Trudy     10
Dick      10
```

How can I write a JOIN to show the table:

```
NAME      APPLES      ORANGES
Alice     5           -
Bob       10          50
Trudy     1           10
Dick      -           10
```

I currently have

```
SELECT a.NAME, APPLES, ORANGES
FROM APPLE a
JOIN
ORANGE o ON o.NAME = a.NAME
```

but that only returns the fields that have a value in both APPLE and ORANGE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.NAME, b.NAME) as NAME, APPLES, ORANGES 
FROM APPLE a 
FULL OUTER JOIN ORANGE o ON o.NAME = a.NAME
```

Comment: Good, it mostly works but now what happens is because I am selecting NAME from a, or from o, whatever names are in one table but not the other will not show up. Any fix for that?

Comment: See above, I added a `COALESCE`.

Comment: Is COALESCE different from NVL>

Comment: @antonpug yes, `COALESCE` accepts any number of values and returns the first non-NULL value. You could use `NVL` in the above query as well.

Comment: you're right RedFilter. After some reading, COALESCE is faster in every cases.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT a.NAME, a.APPLES, o.ORANGES
FROM APPLE a
FULL OUTER JOIN
ORANGE o ON o.NAME = a.NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

should be:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.NAME,o.name) as Name, APPLES, ORANGES 
FROM APPLE a 
FULL OUTER JOIN ORANGE o ON o.NAME = a.NAME
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae9a/4

Answer (score 1):

Change `JOIN` to `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a left right outer join depending on which table contains the inclomplete data